# SharePoint List column formatting based on another column value

Tags: list, sharepoint, conditional-statements, formatting, sharepoint-online

[image: code sample]

I am trying to modify column formatting on the 'Request Approval' column based on the value in the 'Status' column. I'm not getting an error but either get nothing showing in the 'Request Approval' column or it shows the text of the code rather than returning the correct value based on the expression depending on minor edits I've been trying. I suspect a syntax error but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm rather new to this sort of thing so be gentle.

My issues are with `txtContent` and `background-color`. Here is the JSON I am using currently:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Status] == 'Not Approved', [$RequestApproval] = 'Request Approval'), if([$Status] == 'Pending', [$RequestApproval] = 'Request Sent')",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"50c967f4-c651-44a0-ba44-29f89e0aa685\"}"
  },
  "style": {
   "background-color": "= if([$Status] == 'Not Approved', 'blue', if([$Status] == 'Pending', 'orange', if([$Status] == 'Approved', 'green'))",
    "color": "white"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that your JSON statement format is wrong, I have modified it for you, you can try again:

```
    { "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json", 
    "elmType": "button", 
    "txtContent": "=if([$Status] == 'Not Approved', [$RequestApproval] = 'Request Approval',
    if([$Status] == 'Pending', [$RequestApproval] == 'Request Sent'))", "customRowAction": { 
    "action": "executeFlow", 
    "actionParams": "{"id": "50c967f4-c651-44a0-ba44-29f89e0aa685"}" 
    }, 

"style": { 
"background-color": "= if([$Status] == 'Not Approved', 'blue', if([$Status] == 'Pending', 'orange', if([$Status] == 'Approved', 'green')))", 
"color": "white" 
}
}
```

For more information, please refer to:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple syntax issues with your JSON:

1. Flow id parameter and value not properly escaped under `actionParams`
2. `if()` operators are not used properly:

   - It should be in this format: `if(<condition>, <true-result>, <false-result>)`: mention both true and false results
   - Parenthesis/brackets are not closed properly

Here is a sample JSON you can refer to get started with:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Status] == 'Not Approved', 'Request Approval', if([$Status] == 'Pending', 'Request Sent', ''))",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"50c967f4-c651-44a0-ba44-29f89e0aa685\"}"
  },
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if([$Status] == 'Not Approved', 'blue', if([$Status] == 'Pending', 'orange', if([$Status] == 'Approved', 'green', '')))",
    "color": "white"
  }
}
```

Where `Status` is the internal name of your SharePoint column. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)